# How to block CloudMagic from accessing office365 email?

Tags: office365

We have Exchange online and wants to restrict certain email applications from accessing `office 365` emails.

For example, I want to restrict CloudMagic app from accessing my corporate emails.

I've run the following command, but its not working.

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -EwsApplicationAccessPolicy:EnforceBlockList -EwsBlockList:"CloudMagic*"
```

Or

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -EwsApplicationAccessPolicy:EnforceBlockList -EwsBlockList:"CloudMagic"
```

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully blocked CloudMagic by blocking both EWS and ActiveSync. Besides your command, please also run the following command to block ActiveSync access:

```
New-ActiveSyncDeviceAccessRule -AccessLevel Block -Characteristic DeviceType -QueryString CloudMagic
```

Please note that you should wait for several hours for the rules to take effect.